# Column is not present in subquery table, still query is running fine , How?

Tags: sql, oracle

& their sturcture are given below:

1. Structure of Employees table

   ```
   EmployeeID  LastName    FirstName   BirthDate   Photo   Notes
   ```
2. Structure of Customers table

   ```
   CustomerID  CustomerName    ContactName Address City    PostalCode  Country
   ```

Question:
lastname column is not present in customers table then also  why the below query is giving output.

```
select *
from employees
where lastname in (select lastname from customers)
```

can any one please explain this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you have multiple tables in a query, you should *always* qualify column names.  You are intending:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.lastname in (select c.lastname from customers c);
```

This query would -- indeed -- generate an unrecognized column error.

However, SQL in general does you the favor of "looking" for the value in outer queries.  This is called *scoping*.

The compiler looks for `lastname` in `customers`.  It doesn't find it, so it decides that you intend:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.lastname in (select e.lastname from customers c);
```

Answer (score 2):

`where lastname in (select lastname from customers)`

Oracle is using a pseudo-join (*scoping, thanks Gordon*) between Customers and Employees, providing a full list of `lastname` from `employees`

Apply an alias like the below and watch it break:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.lastname in (select c.lastname from customers c)
```

Comment: Thank you  for youy explanation , 

i have one more doubt.

let's insert 2 values in this table.

insert into Employees(EmployeeID,LastName,FirstName) values(11,'GUPTA','GANESH');
insert into Employees(EmployeeID,LastName,FirstName) values(12,'ROHIT','GUPTA');

Comment: suppose i am rewriting my  query

select * from employees where lastname in (select firstname from customers)

As per your logic, it should behave like below query 
select e.*
from employees e
where e.lastname in (select e.firstname from customers c);

and also it should give the output result since 'GUPTA' value is present in firstname and lastname.

but i am not getting any data in output.
please help

Comment: @ganeshgupta Where I said it's like a join, it will compare each row to itself. Maybe try to fix it instead of finding more ways to break it?